# AbstractMethodError attempting a .isValid for a jtds connection

Tags: java, jtds

With the below code, it works perfectly the first time and establishes the connection.  However, the second call that has an existing jtds connection, it throws this error: when checking .isValid()

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
at framework.Utility.queryDatabase(Utility.java:4417)
```

Looking at other answers, I see that it is expected to set a "validationQuery" on the connection?  However, I can't find how to do this when I am not using a datasource, but using the getConnection() method.  Is there another way?  BTW, this works perfectly for a DB2 connection.

Here is the code:

```
    static Connection cJTDSConnection = null;
.
.
.
        Connection cConnection = null;
        .
        .
        .
                case "jtds":
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                if (cJTDSConnection == null || !cJTDSConnection.isValid(15))
                {
                    Log.info("Connecting to database...");
                    cJTDSConnection = getConnection(sDBUrl, sDBUser, sDBPassword);
                    // Commit changes manually
                    cJTDSConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
                    // STEP 3: Execute a query to create statement with required arguments
                    Log.info("**** Connected to Database *******");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.info("No connection needed (already connected)...");
                }
                cConnection = cJTDSConnection;
                break;
```

Thank you!
-Greg